# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'

Tags: python, module, installation

My target host is SUSE 11 but it **does not have access to the internet.**
I was able to install Python 3.6.1 from source but I had to disable pip using --with-ensurepip=no
Otherwise the install failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'
If I try to install pip using get-pip.py I get the same error. (no suprise there)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by following the instructions noted [here](http://linuxcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2016/12/building-python-36-from-source-on.html):

Specifically it was the for loop:

```
for m in _struct binascii unicodedata _posixsubprocess math pyexpat _md5 _sha1 _sha256 _sha512 select _random _socket zlib fcntl; do 
    sed -i "s/^#\(${m}\)/\1/" Modules/Setup; 
done
```

Many thanks to Warren and all who contributed to the post.

Comment: Could you please post your fix? The linked post has a subsequent linked post, and the fix isn't clea ring either of them for this specific error.

Comment: More specifically... running the for loop above in-between configure and make resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same build error, but with pyenv. I'm not sure if my solution will work but hopefully it does.

I spent a good 4 hours searching, and everyone online seems to be saying that Mojave and up is missing some headers and then instructing you to manually download those headers here:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

However I think installing those headers is what actually caused the issue for me.

I don't know if it is actually the proper fix, but going to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and downloading/reinstalling the Command Line Tools is the only thing that worked for me.

After reinstalling the command line tools, I did **not** install the supposedly missing headers. And then I did not experience the build failure mentioning a missing pyexpat module.

Comment: This appears to be the solution for my issue too.
An update of Xcode and associated command line tools WITHOUT installing the headers fixed my issue.
It was the headers that BROKE my install.

Comment: In my case, stuff were broken before the headers (following mojave update), broken after the headers, downloading Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.dmg from the link solved it

Answer (score 2):

The following steps solved this problem for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

After that I installed python with:

```
python-build 3.6.10 ~/.runtimes/Python36
```

(Note that you can change the version as per your requirement)

Also, as mentioned in one of the answers, running

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

after `xcode-select --install` broke things for me again.